# Is there any side effect for using a global top level variable when we are running tests in parallel?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, flutter-bloc

I am here for clarification about unit tests in Flutter.

Here is a typical test snippet that I use to test my flutter_bloc bloc component.

```
void main() {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  ///we have only one data repository which is referred in all blocTests defined
  ///in this file
  DataRepository dataRepository;
  setUp(() {
    dataRepository = mockData.MockDataRepository();
  });

  blocTest('User can login with a valid username and valid password',
      build: () {
       ///code referring dataRepository
        when(dataRepository.login("username","password"))
            .thenAnswer((_) async =>
            mockData.setupSuccessObject(mockData.setupUser()));

        return LoginPageBloc(
          dataRepository: dataRepository,);
      },
      act: (bloc){
    ///...
      },
      expect: [
        ///...
      ],
      verify: () async {
        ///code referring dataRepository
        verify(dataRepository.login("username", "password"))
            .called(1);
      });

  blocTest('User cannot login with invalid username or password',
      build: () {
        ///code referring dataRepository
        when(dataRepository.login("username","password"))
            .thenAnswer((_) async =>
            mockData.setupAuthFailedObject());

        return LoginPageBloc(
            dataRepository: dataRepository,);
      },
      act: (bloc){
        ///...
      },
      expect: [
        ///...
      ],
      verify: () async {
        ///code referring dataRepository
        verify(dataRepository.login("username", "password"))
            .called(1);
      });

}
```

In the above snippet, you can see that the `DataRepostory` object made declared as a top-level variable in order to make the following possible.

1. make the `DataRepository` object accessible for each `blocTest`
   functions
2. make the DataRepository object accessible for each 'build' and
       'verify' methods within the blocTest() method.

My question is,

**is there any side effect for using a global top-level variable like this when we are running tests in parallel?**

Comment: Why don't you just create the repository inside the `build` function of `blocTest`?

Comment: if I create the repository object inside the build function, then how can I refer that repository object inside 'verify' method to verify whether or not the login method get called?

Comment: Your bloc should have a reference to the repository

Comment: yes, bloc has a reference to the repository. But, where should I I keep the reference to the bloc? seems like the bloc object also not available on the 'verify' method. If I keep the bloc instance instead of the datarepository as the top level variable, am I in the same problem of having side effects??

Comment: @RémiRousselet sir, the above tests running green, but I am worrying about the side effects? since the bloc is not available in the 'verify' method, what should I do sir?